# Pick specific part of JSON string and handle in PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm trying to handle some JSON with PHP, and it works fine for now, but I don't really know how I handle a single part of the string. Here is the JSON script:

```
{
  "films": [
    {
      "film_id": "16543",
      "film_name": "Jurassic Park III (2001)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh4.googleusercontent.com\/-RxTBi31EAX4\/VLUjlrnoolI\/AAAAAAAAKoQ\/udX-Xozgvz4\/1415445506a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CE1E06704C481EFC9DB30ECFFE9E7603E4EB1588.C63D78665AFA36AD232F2BE83CA57D9E2047F982&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=32060DD87A9287F2023A5077BD090E09E4F56BD6.9DAF8F78DCB261F72F881D9B308361ADD1B0985A&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=30AC94E2F22ADD6ECB15C66A99BC2C7A87F6899E.3E8BE6D0C2AB23D34154661AB332760926F97EAE&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "3"
    },
    {
      "film_id": "17071",
      "film_name": " The Lost World: Jurassic Park (1997)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh5.googleusercontent.com\/-cKdwk1ZLvX4\/VLUjmhopI0I\/AAAAAAAAKno\/pui10oPTE2Y\/1415510075a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=D41A734EF7D85EF0ED63BA9FD6E6334E5ED03713.9EFB010555B5AAEE09E2A7F8D1AA0EAC3D514478&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CD9512B7D430980F9F0BD80177D99964FEF02483.5D80477BDEE53195448284A75BE343242E57713B&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=BF1C57787BD814984587EBEAA643F693F4DC418.B3445880ECE36BEB1C665E4E1C471EF7C7F7034C&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "2"
    },
    {
      "film_id": "17070",
      "film_name": "Jurassic Park (1993)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-eRAXqWQsXfU\/VLUjmP9Z8mI\/AAAAAAAAKng\/Ru3yngcxgo4\/1415510026a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=C20FEA7A1EC3B1BD13B36093DEC722B1A30B43A.90A7165FF74AE213EFE6B32E3B13A7F2F16C4665&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=9D037782B5F442484EB81AABD738059C629ADD51.C87BDCAEFE4403CE7A2627BB9F4C930BC465033&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CB7826BF0594375D488213E7484D955987126648.BDD3F29107D1E2E65C469142556CE16FB8EE8642&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "1"
    }
  ],
  "catalog_desc": "Overview\r\nAn American science fiction adventure film series based on the novel of the same name by Michael Crichton. The films center on the fictional Isla Nublar near Costa Rica in the Central American Pacific Coast, where a billionaire philanthropist and a small team of genetic scientists have created an amusement park of cloned dinosaurs",
  "catalog_icon": "a",
  "success": 1,
  "message": "successful"
}
```

As you can see there is multiple links in the film_link part

```
"film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CE1E06704C481EFC9DB30ECFFE9E7603E4EB1588.C63D78665AFA36AD232F2BE83CA57D9E2047F982&key=lh1#360#
https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=32060DD87A9287F2023A5077BD090E09E4F56BD6.9DAF8F78DCB261F72F881D9B308361ADD1B0985A&key=lh1#720#
https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=30AC94E2F22ADD6ECB15C66A99BC2C7A87F6899E.3E8BE6D0C2AB23D34154661AB332760926F97EAE&key=lh1#1080#
",
```

But all this is in the same string. How do I get PHP only to pick the last link which ends on #1080#?

Thanks <3 and sorry for my bad english :-/

Comment: Where does that JSON come from? How do you obtain it? How would you approach the problem? What prevents you from approaching it?

Comment: from an dynamic json genarator :)

Comment: Which one? How is it interfaced?

Comment: by php $json_file = file_get_contents('') ? but how is this importan :O?

Comment: Sure, please provide the URI. Your example should be complete. The nature of it being dynamic is important, otherwise you could just change the string.

Comment: not here, it is an private projekt for now, i not planning for public relese atm :-/

Comment: The content is obviously from google and not private. What are you trying to tell me?

Comment: the content is from google yes, but how i use API to get it, dossent matter? and is not an part of my question? i only need to know how to handle the one part, with multiple values :)

Comment: If it's an API there are specs for it. Those specs normally exaplain the format of the field you're trying to parse. That's why it's important. Right now it's not said that those are multiple values.

Comment: all the json look the same as the example above. with multiple links in the film_link part, here i need php only to read #1080# og #720# from the json file, thats the question :)

Comment: (I'm not asking you to share your API key here btw.)Where is `film_link` specified on the vendor's API page?

Comment: i dont know what vendor API is, so i can't anwser that, the only thing i need to know is how to handle the film_link in php by only selecting the last link in the string

Comment: From which server do you get the data = vendor API.

Comment: It does matter as those API site provide documentation explaining the meaning of the diverse data-types which often is necessary to parse the actual data. You might only offer a random result here, a special form, for which splitting the field will work only once. The next time you run this, it's of no use.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the last URL by parsing the whole string over and over again for [the URL fragment](http://php.net/parse_url) but just not too often:

```
$links = 'https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CE1E06704C481EFC9DB30ECFFE9E7603E4EB1588.C63D78665AFA36AD232F2BE83CA57D9E2047F982&key=lh1#360#https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=32060DD87A9287F2023A5077BD090E09E4F56BD6.9DAF8F78DCB261F72F881D9B308361ADD1B0985A&key=lh1#720#https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=30AC94E2F22ADD6ECB15C66A99BC2C7A87F6899E.3E8BE6D0C2AB23D34154661AB332760926F97EAE&key=lh1#1080#';

$link = $links;

$i = max(0, substr_count($link, '#') - 2);
while ($i--)
{
    $link = parse_url($link, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT);
}
```

When done, `$link` contains the URL you're looking for:

> `https://redirector.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=30AC94E2F22ADD6ECB15C66A99BC2C7A87F6899E.3E8BE6D0C2AB23D34154661AB332760926F97EAE&key=lh1#1080#`

It will always take the last URL.

Comment: But this example here return nothing at all :O? do you know why?

Comment: Sure, there is no return statement in it. Please see the example: https://eval.in/298552

Answer (score 0):

```
    $s='{
  "films": [
    {
      "film_id": "16543",
      "film_name": "Jurassic Park III (2001)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh4.googleusercontent.com\/-RxTBi31EAX4\/VLUjlrnoolI\/AAAAAAAAKoQ\/udX-Xozgvz4\/1415445506a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CE1E06704C481EFC9DB30ECFFE9E7603E4EB1588.C63D78665AFA36AD232F2BE83CA57D9E2047F982&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=32060DD87A9287F2023A5077BD090E09E4F56BD6.9DAF8F78DCB261F72F881D9B308361ADD1B0985A&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=4b47af19340093d8&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=30AC94E2F22ADD6ECB15C66A99BC2C7A87F6899E.3E8BE6D0C2AB23D34154661AB332760926F97EAE&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "3"
    },
    {
      "film_id": "17071",
      "film_name": " The Lost World: Jurassic Park (1997)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh5.googleusercontent.com\/-cKdwk1ZLvX4\/VLUjmhopI0I\/AAAAAAAAKno\/pui10oPTE2Y\/1415510075a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=D41A734EF7D85EF0ED63BA9FD6E6334E5ED03713.9EFB010555B5AAEE09E2A7F8D1AA0EAC3D514478&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CD9512B7D430980F9F0BD80177D99964FEF02483.5D80477BDEE53195448284A75BE343242E57713B&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=266dd114ac72413c&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=BF1C57787BD814984587EBEAA643F693F4DC418.B3445880ECE36BEB1C665E4E1C471EF7C7F7034C&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "2"
    },
    {
      "film_id": "17070",
      "film_name": "Jurassic Park (1993)",
      "film_icon": "https:\/\/lh3.googleusercontent.com\/-eRAXqWQsXfU\/VLUjmP9Z8mI\/AAAAAAAAKng\/Ru3yngcxgo4\/1415510026a.jpg",
      "film_link": "https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=18&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=C20FEA7A1EC3B1BD13B36093DEC722B1A30B43A.90A7165FF74AE213EFE6B32E3B13A7F2F16C4665&key=lh1#360#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=22&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=9D037782B5F442484EB81AABD738059C629ADD51.C87BDCAEFE4403CE7A2627BB9F4C930BC465033&key=lh1#720#https:\/\/redirector.googlevideo.com\/videoplayback?requiressl=yes&shardbypass=yes&cmbypass=yes&id=128668d7aed696fb&itag=37&source=picasa&cmo=secure_transport%3Dyes&ip=0.0.0.0&ipbits=0&expire=1428161445&sparams=requiressl,shardbypass,cmbypass,id,itag,source,ip,ipbits,expire&signature=CB7826BF0594375D488213E7484D955987126648.BDD3F29107D1E2E65C469142556CE16FB8EE8642&key=lh1#1080#",
      "film_count": "10",
      "film_sort": "1"
    }
  ],
  "catalog_desc": "Overview\r\nAn American science fiction adventure film series based on the novel of the same name by Michael Crichton. The films center on the fictional Isla Nublar near Costa Rica in the Central American Pacific Coast, where a billionaire philanthropist and a small team of genetic scientists have created an amusement park of cloned dinosaurs",
  "catalog_icon": "a",
  "success": 1,
  "message": "successful"
}';



$json=json_decode( $s, true );
foreach( $json['films'] as $key => $film ){
    if( isset( $film['film_link'] ) ) {
        preg_match_all( '@#\d+#@',$film['film_link'],$matches );
        print_r( $matches );
    }
}
```

Comment: looks a bit like what i need, but i don't understand the script, if i only wants to print the last Array in each string? how would i do that :)?